# building lists of numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, append

I have the following piece of code that builds lists of 2d numpy arrays from data read from a file.

```
rawLambda = np.loadtxt("LambdaM.dat")
rawchi0 = np.loadtxt("chi0M.dat")

npts = len(rawLambda[:,0])//10000

LambdaList = []
chi0List = []
Lambdatmp = np.zeros((100,100),dtype=complex)
chi0tmp = np.zeros((100,100),dtype=complex)
for i in range(npts):
 for l in range(10000):
  ii = i*10000+l
  l1 = int(rawLambda[ii,3]-1)
  l2 = int(rawLambda[ii,4]-1)
  Lambdatmp[l1,l2] = rawLambda[ii,5] + 1.j*rawLambda[ii,6]
  l1 = int(rawchi0[ii,3]-1)
  l2 = int(rawchi0[ii,4]-1)
  chi0tmp[l1,l2] = rawchi0[ii,5] + 1.j*rawchi0[ii,6]
  
 LambdaList.append(Lambdatmp)
 chi0List.append(chi0tmp)
```

If I try to retrieve individual arrays from chi0List, for example,

```
for i in range(npts):
 tst = np.sum(chi0List[i])
 print(i,tst)
```

The result indicates that all arrays in the list are identical to the last one appended. Could someone please tell what am I doing wrong here?! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using numpy or lists you should be aware of what you are copying. The arrays you append to the list is just shallow copies of the arrays. All of them point to the same array. While appending you should create a copy in order to not append a pointer to the same list like

```
LambdaList.append(Lambdatmp.copy())
chi0List.append(chi0tmp.copy())
```

Answer (score 0):

Its because you dont create new lists

```
chi0tmp = np.zeros((100,100),dtype=complex)
```

This gives a single array in memory that you change in place. Appending only drops a view of that array in your list that gets changed with each loop. To fix this create your temp array within your outer for loop